# Why does my code not work? It passed the base case but after that it got stuck. The Question is "Non Repeating Numbers" on GFG

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, bit-manipulation

The Approach I took was I first used bit manipulation to find that first element which was unique in the variable "c", then i used another array to copy the elements of the original array, but without the repeating element, and then used the bit manipulation method again to find the 2nd unique element in "C1".After that since I needed to return an array i added both values to the array "a" and returned it.

```
class Solution
{
    public int[] singleNumber(int[] nums)
    {
        int a[]=new int[2];
        int c=0,c1=0;
        for(int i1:nums)
        c=c^nums[i1];
        a[0]=c;
        int b[]=new int[nums.length-1];
         for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if (nums[i] == c) {
                continue;
            }
            b[k++] = nums[i];
        }
        for(int i2:b)
        c1=c1^b[i2];
        a[1]=c1;
        return a;
        
    }
}
```

[This is the link for the Question](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/finding-the-numbers0215/1#)

Comment: Let's say two unique values are `x1` and `x2`. In your code, variable `c` is not the first unique value. Instead,  `c = x1 ^ x2`.

Comment: @Haoliang but when i individually checked the value of a[0] or c, i got X1, and the same goes true of a[1] or c1.

Comment: Just found another problem: in the for loop, `c=c^nums[i1];` should be `c = c^i1`.

Comment: @Haoliang made the change and got this error
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 5
 at Solution.singleNumber(File.java:51)
 at GFG.main(File.java:24)"

Comment: Since we've made changes to the first loop. Now `c = x1 ^ x2`. For example, if the input is `{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4}`, then `c = 3 ^ 4 = 7`. Your second for loop is no longer applicable, since there's no element equals 7.

Comment: @Haoliang please help me correct it, should i change the entire logic and go with the 1's and 2's compliment method? Is there no way this approach could work?

Comment: The question says expected space complexity is O(1), yours is O(N).

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

- expected space complexity is O(1), your is O(N)
- as mentioned by @Haoliang: the result of xoring all elements is a ^ b (the xor of the two missing elements) and not one of the answers (a or b), so your logic doesn't work

Here is how you can solve it:

1. xor all elements => a ^ b
2. find a bit that is 1 in a ^ b (there has to be a bit that is one if a != b which is the case)
3. xor all numbers that have that bit set and all number that have that bit not set, this will give you a and b

```java
public int[] solve (int[] arr) {
    int xor = 0, a = 0, b = 0;
    for (int x : arr)
        xor ^= x;
    int mask = 1;
    while ((mask & xor) == 0)
        mask <<= 1;
    for (int x : arr) {
        if ((mask & x) == 0)
            a ^= x;
        else
            b ^= x;
    }
    return a < b ? new int[] {a, b} : new int[] {b, a};
}
```